# MovieClip progress bar width is too small relative to parent container

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am new to ActionScripot and Flash and I am stuck with the following problem:

On the stage I have a movieclip (Container, originally 200px width) and inside it with a progressbar movieclip (originally 700px width), scaled with Free Transform Tool to fit the parent container. The width of the container changes run-time while resizing the scene.

In ActionScript I have a function which should set the progress bar width according to a calculated percentage value:

```
private function updateProgress(event:TimerEvent):void
{
   var barWidth:int = _container.width;
   var progress:Number = _stream.time / _stream.duration * barWidth;
   _progressBar.width = progress;           
}
```

My problem is that the progressBar even at full time (100%) is only at 1/4 of the parent container. I assume that it comes from the symbols original size.

Can I correct this programatically, or I must redesign it with the "designer"?

I hope I made clear my problem, as I said, I'm new in Flash.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your **_progressBar** has its **scaleX** set by the designer.
What you could do is store the initial **scaleX** and change your function to:

```
... 
var barScaleX = _progressBar.scaleX;
...
private function updateProgress(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    var progress:Number = _stream.time / _stream.duration;
   _progressBar.scaleX = barScaleX * progress;
}
```

This should set the width of the progressbar by a percentage of it's original scale.

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the barWidth with the amount of the times scaled or write the original width = 700px